# Irrationality of the integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Does there exist any rational $t$, such that $|t|<1/10$ and the integral $$\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int\limits_0^{\pi t}\arccos{\left(\frac{\sin{s}}{1+2\sin{s}}\right)}ds$$ is irrational?

The integral is from http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7464 where it is explained why it is desirable to get the answer to this question.

Comment: Well, the author himself says that the problem to decide whether the above integral is rational or not is a difficult problem. 
Do you believe otherwise ?
 

Comment: I agree with the author that the problem seems to be difficult. But sometimes difficult problems have simple enough solutions. Examples are http://www.mateforum.ro/articole/irationale_faimoase.pdf http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf and http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506086

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right. There are certainly experts for such a
question (and, e.g.,  Zudilin has a user account for mathoverflow). 
